# random array in c

Tags: c, arrays

Two functions in the program, one displaying each value with corresponding row, column and address. Second function displays high and low with corresponding row, column and address and the average of the values.

First function works. The high low and average function displays garbage. I am supposed to use array notation but I'm not sure how to pass the values properly. The high/low/average function alone will execute properly, but when the show_it function is put in, the values are not right. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int show_it (int, int);
int hi_lo_avg (int, int);

int main()
{
 int a[3][5];
 int r, c;
 srandom( (unsigned) time(NULL));
 a[0][0] = random() % 100 +1;
 show_it(r,c);
 hi_lo_avg(r,c);
 return 0;
 }

int show_it(int r, int c)
{   
int a[3][5];
for (r = 0; r < 3; r++)
   for (c=0; c < 5; c++)
{
   a[r][c]=random()%100+1;
  printf("\nValue %d is found at row %d, column %d", a[r][c], r, c);
  printf(" with an address of %p", &a[r][c]);
}
return 0;
}


 int hi_lo_avg (int r, int c)
 {
 int a[3][5];
 int max = 0;
 int max_r, max_c;
 int min_r, min_c;
 int min = 100;
 min = a[0][0];
 for (r=0; r<3; r++)
     for (c=0; c<5; c++)
 {
   a[r][c]=random()%100+1;
   if (a[r][c]>max)
   {
    max = a[r][c];
    max_r = r;
    max_c = c;
   }
 }
 printf("High %d, at row %d, col %d address of %p\n", max, max_r, max_c, &a[max_r][max_c]);

for (r=0; r<3; r++)
   for (c=0; c<5; c++)
{
   if (a[r][c]<min)
  {
       min=a[r][c];
       min_r = r;
       min_c = c;
  }
}
printf("Low %d, at row %d, col %d address of %p\n", min, min_r, min_c, &a[min_r][min_c]); 

int total = 0;
float average = 0.0;
for (r=0; r<3; r++)
   for (c=0; c<5; c++)
{    
total = total + a[r][c];
}
array_average = (float)total/11;
printf("\nThe array average is %f\n", array_average);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues. The first is **always include warnings in your compile string** and really pay attention to them. With (and without) warnings enabled `-Wall -Wextra` you receive:

```
hiloavg.c: In function ‘hi_lo_avg’:
hiloavg.c:67:5: error: ‘array_average’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    array_average = (float) total / 11;
    ^
```

Looking at the respective line you find:

```
array_average = (float) total / 11;
```

The compiler has no idea what `array_average` is because it has never been declared in function `hi_lo_avg`. (you do have `average` declared as `float average = 0.0;` which I suspect is what you meant.) You can either declare it earlier as a `float` (as you did the **unused variable `average`**) or declare it here at its first use:

```
float array_average = (float) total / 11;
```

or as you probably intended:

```
average = (float) total / 11;  // you also need to change the printf as well
printf ("\nThe array average is %f\n", average);
```

Fixing that error alone with allow your program to return the `"values"` (are they correct?):

```
Value 83 is found at row 0, column 0 with an address of 0x7ffff0c06050
Value 95 is found at row 0, column 1 with an address of 0x7ffff0c06054
..
Value 95 is found at row 2, column 3 with an address of 0x7ffff0c06084
Value 31 is found at row 2, column 4 with an address of 0x7ffff0c06088
(newline inserted for readability)
High 95, at row 1, col 4 address of 0x7ffff0c06054
Low 1, at row 31, col 95 address of 0x7ffff0c06418

The array average is 70.818184
```

The `col` value for `Low` looks suspect... But first, you have other telling warnings:

```
hiloavg.c: In function ‘main’:
hiloavg.c:13:13: warning: ‘r’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    show_it (r, c);
            ^
hiloavg.c:13:13: warning: ‘c’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

This brings up another critical point that will bite you more times than not: **always initialize your variables.** Simply set them to `0` (or `NULL` in the case of a pointer). It will save you a lot of grief in the long run.

```
int r = 0;
int c = 0;
```

The remaining warnings:

```
hiloavg.c: In function ‘main’:
hiloavg.c:9:9: warning: variable ‘a’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int a[3][5];
        ^
hiloavg.c: In function ‘hi_lo_avg’:
hiloavg.c:63:11: warning: unused variable ‘average’ [-Wunused-variable]
    float average = 0.0;
        ^
```

Here the compiler is warning you **"Hey!, Here is stuff you had me compile, but you are not doing anything with -- take a look and fix it.** Looking at `a`, in `main()`, you declare it and assign a value to the first element, but then do nothing with it:

```
a[0][0] = random () % 100 + 1;
```

If you don't need it, get rid of it. As to the last warning: `warning: unused variable ‘average’` -- I bet you recognize that from the earlier discussion of `‘array_average’ undeclared` (changing all to `average` cured the problem).

Now your program will compile **without warning** and it should give you confidence that at least the compiler is happy with what you did:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/hiloavg hiloavg.c
```

Take time to understand all the output. It is very detailed for a reason and will help you learn and become a much better programmer.

Now let's look at some of the other problems plaguing you logic/correctness of the answers. The first glaring problem is you **reinitialize `a`** in both `show_it` and `hi_lo_avg`. That's nuts. Your `hi_lo_avg` answer will **never** correspond to the data you just printed with `show_it`. The fix is relatively easy. Initialize `a` in `main()` and pass it to both `show_it` and `hi_lo_avg`. The following example shows you how. Also pay attention to how `row` and `col` are `#define`'ed. If you have questions, drop a comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define row 3
#define col 5

int show_it (int a[][col], int, int);
int hi_lo_avg (int a[][col], int, int);

int main () {

    int a[row][col] = {{0}};                      /* initialize all values to 0   */
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;

    srandom ((unsigned) time (NULL));

    for (r = 0; r < row; r++)                     /* fill the array               */
        for (c = 0; c < col; c++)
            a[r][c] = random () % 100 + 1;

    show_it (a, row, col);
    hi_lo_avg (a, row, col);

    return 0;
}

int show_it (int a[][col], int r, int c) 
{
    for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            a[r][c] = random () % 100 + 1;
            printf ("\nValue %2d is found at row %d, column %d", a[r][c], r,
                    c);
            printf (" with an address of %p", &a[r][c]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int hi_lo_avg (int a[][col], int r, int c)
{
    int max = 0;
    int max_r, max_c;
    int min_r, min_c;
    int min = 100;
    int total = 0;
    float average = 0.0;

    for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            if (a[r][c] > max) {
                max = a[r][c];
                max_r = r;
                max_c = c;
            }
            if (a[r][c] < min) {
                min = a[r][c];
                min_r = r;
                min_c = c;
            }
            total += a[r][c];
        }
    }

    printf ("\n\nHigh %2d, at row %d, col %d address of %p\n", max, max_r, max_c,
            &a[max_r][max_c]);

    printf ("Low  %2d, at row %d, col %d address of %p\n", min, min_r, min_c,
            &a[min_r][min_c]);

    average = (float)total / (float)(row * col);
    printf ("\nThe array average is %f\n\n", average);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Value 95 is found at row 0, column 0 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c60
Value  2 is found at row 0, column 1 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c64
Value 12 is found at row 0, column 2 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c68
Value 99 is found at row 0, column 3 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c6c
Value 32 is found at row 0, column 4 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c70
Value  5 is found at row 1, column 0 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c74
Value  9 is found at row 1, column 1 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c78
Value 21 is found at row 1, column 2 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c7c
Value 67 is found at row 1, column 3 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c80
Value 88 is found at row 1, column 4 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c84
Value 55 is found at row 2, column 0 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c88
Value 70 is found at row 2, column 1 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c8c
Value 87 is found at row 2, column 2 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c90
Value 70 is found at row 2, column 3 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c94
Value 40 is found at row 2, column 4 with an address of 0x7ffff3ec3c98

High 99, at row 0, col 3 address of 0x7ffff3ec3c6c
Low   2, at row 0, col 1 address of 0x7ffff3ec3c64

The array average is 50.133335
```

Comment: You explained everything REALLY well and made it much easier to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. C is a wonderful language, but it is an exact language. It takes a little more work to master, but it is well worth the effort. Keep up the good work and if it seems like it takes a long time to get comfortable with all the nuances of C -- it should, you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use r and c in the printf function because r and c will become 3 and 5 when the loop finished. You code should change like this:

```
int hi_lo_avg (int r, int c)
{
  int a[3][5];
  int max = 0;
  int max_r, max_c; // use these variables to mark down the max row/column position
  int min_r, min_c; // use these variables to mark down the min row/column position
  int min = 100;

  for (r=0; r<3; r++)
    for (c=0; c<5; c++)
    {
      a[r][c]=random()%100+1;
      if (a[r][c]>max)
      {
        max = a[r][c];
        max_r = r;
        max_c = c;
      }
    }
  printf("High %d, at row %d, col %d address of %p\n", max, max_r, max_c, &a[max_r][max_c]);

for (r=0; r<3; r++)
   for (c=0; c<5; c++)
{
   if (a[r][c]<min)
  {
       min=a[r][c];
       min_r = r;
       min_c = c;
  }
}
printf("Low %d, at row %d, col %d address of %p\n", min, min_r,min_c, &a[min_r][min_c]); 
return 0;
}
```